# FreeCAD alternatives for parametric 3D geometry with Python3

Tags: python, 3d

What are alternatives to using FreeCAD libraries for generating, modifying, and exporting parametric 3D geometry in Python3?
It is a plus if modules provide primitive objects such as box, sphere, and cylinder, as well as boolean operations on geometry.
Modules available via pypi or options with documentation for how to run in virtualenv are preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sorting through projects that were not updated for ages, and filtering projects that are "just" working on meshes, I am left with one potential alternative to FreeCAD:

CadQuery
https://github.com/CadQuery/cadquery

I have not tried it out yet, so I can't speak to similarities or differences between CadQuery and FreeCAD.